# Pinescript code lines that gives one decimal for each order

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWXwL.png)

Is there any lines or code that can make my order entries with one decimal instead of 3, because i am using bybit and it only allows orders with one decimal. I would like to backtest it with one decimal to have more precise results.

I tried using math floor with order qty but it didn't work. are there any suggestions on what i should try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just truncate the number by multiplying by 10, rounding and dividing by 10 again to get the quantity with one decimal.

See this example:

```
//@version=5
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true, process_orders_on_close=true, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=100, precision=6)

in_one_dec = input.bool(false, "Use one decimal?")

entry_qty = (strategy.equity / close)
entry_qty_adj = in_one_dec ? int(entry_qty * 10) / 10 : entry_qty

plotchar(entry_qty, "entry_qty", "")
plotchar(entry_qty_adj, "entry_qty_adj", "")

longCondition = ta.crossover(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long, qty=entry_qty_adj)

shortCondition = ta.crossunder(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short, qty=entry_qty_adj)
```

Comment: OMG THANKS, appreciate a lot!! crazy man thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use math.round(YOUR_NUMBER,1).